# How to disable a dropdown list item when dropdown list is bound dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

Dropdown list is bound dynamically as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSource" class="ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="FROM1" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyName">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FROM1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PIMSConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyName] FROM Company ORDER BY [CompanyName]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />
```

The `CompanyName` table has a value that is equal to "Select" and I want this value to be shown in the dropdown list but should be grayed out (disabled) so users can't select or set it.

Any idea how to do it in ASP.NET (not HTML)?

Comment: You want something like `<optgroup>` html tag or that some of `listitems` be `disabled`? I asked because I don't understand fully Your question (sorry).

Comment: @nelek I want one `ListItem` to be disabled. This `ListItem` value is bound with the drop down list dynamically from a SQL Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is complete answer based on other questions from comments.

Make `ListItems` disabled and put them on the top of `ddlSource` based on condition `CompanyName="Select"` :

aspx :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSource" class="ddl" runat="server" > </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FROM1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PIMSConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
```

code behind :

```
public void PopDDL()
{
    FORM1.SelectCommand = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Company ORDER BY CASE WHEN CompanyName='Select' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;"
    ddlSource.DataSourceID = "FORM1";
    ddlSource.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
    ddlSource.DataValueField = "CompanyName";
    ddlSource.DataBind();
    foreach (ListItem itm in ddlSource.Items) {
        if (itm.Value == "Select") {
            itm.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PopDDL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but populating `ddlSource` will be from code behind (it's in vb.net, sorry) :

```
     Public Sub PopDDL()
        FORM1.SelectCommand = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Company ORDER BY CompanyName;"
        ddlSource.DataSourceID = "FORM1"
        ddlSource.DataTextField = "CompanyName"
        ddlSource.DataValueField = "CompanyName"
        ddlSource.DataBind()
        For Each itm As ListItem In ddlSource.Items
            If itm.Value = *your_condition* Then  'condition why this item must be disabled
                itm.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PopDDL()
    End Sub
```

Item will be displayed but disabled (gray).

Update :
I use conversion tool (vb.net to c#) and I think this is c# code :

```
foreach (ListItem itm in ddlSource.Items) {
    if (itm.Value == *your_contidion*) { 'condition why this item must be disabled
        itm.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

If You use `itm.Enabled = False`, item will not be showed.

**UPDATE #2 (converted to c# code by online converter) :**

aspx page :

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSource" class="ddl" runat="server" > </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FROM1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PIMSConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
   <br />
```

code behind :

```
public void PopDDL()
{
    FORM1.SelectCommand = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Company ORDER BY CompanyName;";
    ddlSource.DataSourceID = "FORM1";
    ddlSource.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
    ddlSource.DataValueField = "CompanyName";
    ddlSource.DataBind();
    foreach (ListItem itm in ddlSource.Items) {
        if (itm.Value == *your_condition*) {
            itm.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PopDDL();
}
```

Comment: Can I add this forloop code in `Page_Load` event? cause data is bound with the dropdown object in .aspx file.

Comment: @Rehan No, because `ddlSource` isn't yet populated, rendered... I try that at first place. Just remove `DataSourceID`, `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` from `ddlSource` and in `FORM1` set `SelectCommand=""`. This is same thing, just binding is in code behind. Put, in vb.net case, subroutine in `Page_Load` and `ddlSource` will be populated after every postback. By my example, `ddlSource` is populated and You can do with his items what You want.

Comment: If `ddlSource` isnt populated when page loads, when does it get populated?

Comment: `PopDDL` (in my example) populating `ddlSource`... try, both versions : insert only forloop code in `Page_Load` and 2nd ver. how I wrote in example. You'll see differences. Only `forloop` code in `Page_load` will be executed before `ddlSource` is populated.

Comment: See my example : `FORM1.SelectCommand="SELECT CompanyName FROM Company` and then `ddlSource.DataSourceID="FORM1"`

Comment: btw. I strongly suggest You to change that `ID` of `SqlDataSource` from `FROM1` to something else. When You create new apsx page there is `<form id="form1"...`  isn't?

Comment: Yes, I see that... my bad ;)

Comment: btw, how to bring this disabled itemlist to the top of the list?

Comment: @Rehan for example `SELECT CompanyName FROM Company ORDER BY *your_condition_from_forloop_code*, CompanyName;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83661/discussion-between-nelek-and-rehan).

Comment: `SELECT CompanyName FROM Company WHERE CompanyName='Select' ORDER BY CompanyName`. But it only selects one item, not all of the list.

Comment: @Rehan I deleted my perv. comment, but not enough fast :( ... I send new comment... don't use `where` in condition... there is new comment, changed... `SELECT CompanyName FROM Company ORDER BY *your_condition_from_forloop_code*, CompanyName;`  ... btw. Some of Your records of `CompanyName` field content value `select`?

Comment: `*your_condition_from_forloop_code*` = `CompanyName='Select'`. Can you please reformat your query?